# How to add a border to layout?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I would like to add a border to a layout, but I can't. This is the layout:

```
HPOUT1L_layout = QHBoxLayout()
HPOUT1L_layout.addLayout(HPOUT1L_connectors_layout)
HPOUT1L_layout.addWidget(lbl_HPOUT1L)
```

I tried using styles, but it didn't work.
Perhaps I could use QFrames instead, but I have to do a lot of changes.

Comment: You could look at QGroupBox or at [style sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html)

Comment: What about `HPOUT1L_layout.setContentsMargins(left, top, right, bottom)`?

Comment: Layouts aren't visible GUI elements, so they cannot have borders. You must put the layout in a `QFrame`, or some similar widget.

Comment: Mmm.. yeah, I just figured out. As alternative I was planning to add a separator widget between two layouts, but perhaps I need to post another question.

Answer (score 4):

It is not clear what you mean by "a lot of changes".

You could insert your layout in a [QFrame](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qframe.html).

[image]

- On the top, you can see a simple verticalLayout with two buttons.
- On the bottom, the same verticalLayout inside a QFrame.

Comment: Hello, could you provide the code of the example? Thanks.